# group by in python with columns having N/A values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe frame:

```
                    x                  y                z    city
        0       -0.459476              NaN              NaN   hyd
        0             NaN        20.439870              NaN   hyd
        0             NaN              NaN         1.142743   hyd
        0             N/A              NaN              NaN   pune
        0             NaN         9.827238              NaN   pune
        0             NaN              NaN       -99.950162   pune
```

I want the above data frame to group by city and produce the below result:

```
                x                      y              z    city
            -0.459476              20.439870      1.142743 hyd
               N/A                 9.827238     -99.950162 pune
```

I am using the below code:

```
newdf = frame[frame.columns[:3]]
newdf1 = list(newdf.columns.values)
df1 = frame.groupby(city)[newdf1].sum().reset_index()
```

The result does not give me the column x as it as N/A.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

**`groupby`** with **`ffill`** **`bfill`** then **`drop_duplicates`**

```
df.groupby('city').ffill().bfill().drop_duplicates(keep='first')

          x          y          z  city
0 -0.459476  20.439870   1.142743   hyd
3       N/A   9.827238 -99.950162  pune
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. i want the 2nd row to be with the value N/A not NaN. How do i get that. Thanks

Comment: I just updated my answer.  When I copied over your dataframe, `N/A` was converted to NaN, when I fixed that, I get your desired output.